# How to compile custom Linux Kernel on/for AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kernel, socketcan

We have this AARCH64 instance that wasn't compiled with SocketCAN module.
CONFIG_CAN_VCAN=m

What is the best way to fix this ?

If it is to rebuild the kernel, where can we find the complete process for downloading the right sources, etc.

Thx

Comment: Can't you insert the Linux module for it?

Comment: From what i read, re-compiling the entire Linux is the only option.... I can check... Don't know how to do this.